# Skype can't use the webcam because Skype is using it

Tags: windows, skype, webcam

I can answer a call with audio or make a call with audio, but when I try to enable video, Skype complains that something else is using the webcam. I track that down with Process Explorer only to find out that the process that is using the webcam is...Skype.exe. I tried ending process Skype.exe and starting Skype again, but this problem remains. Is this a known problem? Is there a known workaround? Is there a way to tell Skype while it is running that it is the one that is using the webcam and get its stuff together?

Update: I killed the process and then rebooted the computer and, for now, the webcam works with Skype again.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Skype?